# Missing igraph_es_end function from igraph 0.6.5

Tags: c, igraph

It seems that the C interface of `igraph 0.6.5` on `Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64` is missing the functions:

```
igraph_es_end
igraph_es_next
```

My compiler prints "igraph_es_end" was not declared in this scope. Someone else has this problem?

Comment: Maybe you are not linking to the igraph library. Btw. note that igraph 0.6.5 is more than two years old now.

Comment: No, everything is linked fine, because other functions were working perfectly. I've solved by compiling manually igraph 0.7.1 from source, because on Ubuntu 14.04 the package is outdated.